# Customising OpenFileDialog: Help button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, openfiledialog

I would like to disable Help button or change its behaviour (currently it opens https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2004439) on OpenFileDialog window.

I hoped to use `IFileDialogCustomize::RemoveControlItem()` or `IFileDialogCustomize::SetControlItemState(, , CDCS_INACTIVE)`. However, I don't know how to find `dwIDItem` for the Help button. Inspect.exe tool gives the following information:

```
hwnd=0x0000000000090958 64bit class="DirectUIHWND" style=0x56000000 ex=0x10000
Name: "&Help"
ControlType: UIA_ButtonControlTypeId (0xC350)
```

So, can I disable/hide this button or change its behaviour? If so, are there any examples of how this is done?

[image: OpenFileDialog]

Comment: Just hide the button via its [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.showhelp?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)? Also see the HelpRequested Event mentioned in the help linked if you want to change behavior.

Comment: Have you tried hiding it via that property? It is not related to that button I am talking about at all.

Comment: You talk about the help Button and that is the property to show/hide the help button. What could have i misinterpreted? And no i just read the documentation.

Comment: I have provided an image and highlighted the Help button I am interested. Your mentioned method adds an extra Help button next to Open and Cancel buttons. So, it is no relevant to my question at all.

Comment: Might be. When checking it now this switches between the current OpenFileDialog and the legacy Pre-Vista one so does something totally unrelated and uncomparable. Lets state that it does not help and (for me) code is broken just like the documentation that seems to document something that was valid before the Vista! release. Gem from the source code `UnexpectedOptions = NativeMethods.OFN_SHOWHELP //If ShowHelp is true, we don't use the Vista Dialog`. Be aware that F1 also opens the online help and it does not seem to have any connection to this button.